# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Something went wrong while trying to open the window

Tags: javascript, push-notification, web-push

I'm getting above error, while trying to open new link while clicking the web push notification.

My code is working fine, i mean i am able to open the link after clicking the notification but getting this error in console, also when i am putting any hardcoded url then its showing not error in console.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is my service-worker.js code

```
var link;
try{
self.addEventListener('push', function(e) {
    var data = e.data.json();
    var title = data.title;

        var options = {
            body: data.body
        };
        if(data.link){
            link = data.link;
        }

        if(data.badge){
            options.badge = data.badge;
        }

        if(data.icon){
            options.icon = data.icon;
        }

        if(data.image){
            options.image = data.image;
        }

        e.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));

 });
}
  catch(error){
  console.log('error while sending push notification');
}
 self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {

 event.notification.close();
 event.waitUntil(clients.openWindow(link));
});
```

Comment: Could you provide a working fiddle? it will be easier to debug

Comment: I am making server calls and all, so its difficult to provide. Everything is working as excepected but getting a console error in this line `event.waitUntil(clients.openWindow(link));`

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue while trying to implement click action on web push notifications. Using `preventDefault()` resolved it;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: didnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and wasn't able to find any solutions online. For me, this happened when the URL I was using didn't have a protocol.

```
event.waitUntil(clients.openWindow("http://localhost:3000/app")); // Works
event.waitUntil(clients.openWindow("localhost:3000/app")); // Does not work
```